# What do do with a rusted (not seized) nut

Tags: rust

A nut on my bike is rusted and doesn't  accept a bolt beyond first few threads.

What can I do about it short of grinding it off and welding a new one on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a freeing fluid such as "plus-gas" (btw WD40 is not the same WD stands for Water Displacement...) and gently work the bolt through. I have had success with getting a duplicate bolt and putting a hacksaw cut into the threads to help chase the rust out.

Or get the correct tap and re-tap the threads in the nut.

Comment: Here's an example of working it through: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_K1fWUBw4pQ

Answer (score 1):

I would "clean" the rust out by re-tapping with the proper thread tap.

[image: Thread tapping]

[image]

Comment: The image shows what is called a bottoming tap - a starting tap has a more pronounced taper and is easier to start.

Comment: Spot on.  Honestly, I'd use [and have used] the "bolt slot" method if it wasn't for the fact I own a machine shop and drawers chuck full of taps.  If the bolt, when tight, extends several threads past the nut, you can make a minor cut on the tip and use the same bolt.  But I'm one of those people that can't imagine not owning every single tool - usually purchased *after* I use some shadetree method.  For next time, see...

Comment: I used the bolt-slot method out in the middle of a field on a tractor - no drawers of kit available :) :) just what you can come up with...

Comment: If there's no room for a tap there are socket sized adapters.